# Calculating fitted parameter error estimates and correlations (covariance matrix) using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

My colleague has fitted a model using:

```
res = optimize.minimize(f,x0,method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
```

res (of type OptimizeResult) does not seem to contain any estimate of the errors on the fitted parameters, nor does it return a covariance matrix so that I can see the correlations between the parameters. Is it possible to get at these? My colleague is using the 'SLSQP' method as it easily facilitates parameter constraints and bounds, but moving to another method *could* be acceptable.

res does contain the Jacobian matrix. Is there some method of translation?

Thanks in advance!